# Use LIKE for strings in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to make a function that search in a table and returns rows that contain a certain word that I Insert like below. But when I use LIKE it give me an error: Incorrect syntax near '@perberesi'

```
CREATE FUNCTION perberesit7
(@perberesi varchar(100))
RETURNS @menu_rest TABLE 
(emri_hotelit varchar(50), 
emri_menuse varchar(50), 
perberesit varchar(255))
AS
Begin
   insert into @menu_rest
   Select  dbo.RESTORANTET.Emri_Rest, dbo.MENU.Emri_Pjatës, dbo.MENU.Pershkrimi
   From RESTORANTET, MENU
   Where dbo.MENU.Rest_ID=dbo.RESTORANTET.ID_Rest and
          dbo.MENU.Pershkrimi LIKE %@perberesi%

   return

End
```

Pleae help me...How can I use LIKE in this case

Comment: Do you have any reason to use multistep TVF instead of inline TVF ?

Comment: The reason you're getting the error you are is because your LIKE clause has no single quotes to denote the string you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just realized that you are creating a function, which means that you **can't** use `INSERT`. You should also really take Gordon's advice and use explicit joins and table aliases.

```
CREATE FUNCTION perberesit7(@perberesi varchar(100))
RETURNS @menu_rest TABLE (  emri_hotelit varchar(50), 
                            emri_menuse varchar(50), 
                            perberesit varchar(255))
AS
Begin
   return(
   Select  R.Emri_Rest, M.Emri_Pjatës, M.Pershkrimi
   From RESTORANTET R
   INNER JOIN MENU M
        ON M.Rest_ID = R.ID_Rest
   Where M.Pershkrimi LIKE '%' + @perberesi + '%')
End
```

Comment: `A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.`

Comment: http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/  - The begin and end turn this into a slow multi line function.  LIKE with '%' + @perberesi will cause scans.

Answer (score 2):

try using:
        `'%' + @perberesi + '%'`

instead of:
        `%@perberesi%`

[Some Examples](http://forums.asp.net/t/1256985.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to define the return table?

The following is a inline table variable function that performs better than a multi-line table.  I wrote one to return columns that have the two letters 'id'.  Just modify for your own case.

See article from Wayne Sheffield.

http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/archive/2012/02/comparing-inline-and-multistatement-table-valued-functions/

```
-- Use tempdb
use tempdb;
go

-- Simple ITVF
create function search_columns (@name varchar(128))
returns TABLE
return
(
select * from sys.columns where name like '%' + @name + '%'
)
go

-- Call the function
select * from search_columns('id');
go
```

However, since you have a '%' in the like clause at the front of the expression, a full table or index scan is likely.  You might want to look at full text indexing if you data is large.

http://craftydba.com/?p=1629